# How to go through and display all data for this JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file for example named data.json which look like this:

```
{
  "item1": {
    "details": [
      {
        "data": "2015-06-11 11:30:00",
        "link": "http:/link.com"
      },
      {
        "data": "2015-06-10 11:30:00",
        "link": "http:/link.com"
      },
      {
        "data": "2015-06-09 11:30:00",
        "link": "http:/link.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "item2": {
    "details": [
      {
        "data": "2015-06-11 11:30:00",
        "link": "http:/link.com"
      },
      {
        "data": "2015-06-10 11:30:00",
        "link": "http:/link.com"
      },
      {
        "data": "2015-06-09 11:30:00",
        "link": "http:/link.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a structure in HTML where I want to append positions to the menu which will be created from "item1" and "item2" for example

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="display_link">item1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="display_link">item2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then after click on one of those appended link I want to trigger some function which will take "data" and "link" and append them to the links ID which should look like this for example:

```
<ul id="links">
    <li><span>Data: 2015-06-11 11:30:00</span><a href="http:/link.com">http:/link.com</a></li>          
</ul>
```

For now what I have is the script which load data form .json file and append links to the menu, but I don`t know how to append links to the page after click on menu item :/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "js/aa_dashboard.json",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response)
        {
            console.log(response); 
            var menu_items = [];
            for(var key in response) {
                 console.log(key); 
                 $('#menu_custom').append(
                    '<li><a class="display_link" href="#">'+key+'</a></li>'
                 );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: first menu_custom is available in dom or not

Comment: yes element exist in dom it is static html <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" id="menu_custom">

          </ul>

Comment: then u r having code right

Comment: on clicking `item1` and `item2` you will go no where because `href="#"` will redirect to no where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   data = {
      "item1": {
        "details": [
          {
            "data": "2015-06-11 11:30:00",
            "link": "http:/link.com"
          },
          {
            "data": "2015-06-10 11:30:00",
            "link": "http:/link.com"
          },
          {
            "data": "2015-06-09 11:30:00",
            "link": "http:/link.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "item2": {
        "details": [
          {
            "data": "2015-06-11 11:30:00",
            "link": "http:/link.com"
          },
          {
            "data": "2015-06-10 11:30:00",
            "link": "http:/link.com"
          },
          {
            "data": "2015-06-09 11:30:00",
            "link": "http:/link.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    };

    $(function(){
      for(var key in data) {
        $('#menu_custom').append(
          '<li id="' + key + '"><a class="display_link" href="#" onclick="loadItemlinks(\'' + key + '\')">'+key+'</a></li>'
        );
      }
      
      
    });

function loadItemlinks(clickedItem){
        var links = "ul";
        for(var i = 0; i < data[clickedItem].details.length; i++){
          var currentLinkDetail = data[clickedItem].details[i];
          links += '<li><a href="' + currentLinkDetail.link + '">' + currentLinkDetail.data + '</a></li>';
        }
        links += "</ul>";
        $("#" + clickedItem).append(links);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu_custom">

</ul>
```

Comment: This is it thanks! No i know what i was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly as you have appended the list items in #menu_custom, you can keep a blank div on your page:-

```
<div id="item-details"></div>
```

Or if you don't have initial control on dom then you can append this to your body by :-

Then on click of every item you can set the html of the item content into the item-details div.

```
$("#item-details").html(itemDetailHtml);
```

where itemDetailHtml can be created in a similar way as you created the list items html.

Comment: The really difficulty for me is how to bind onclick function to thedynamically added menu items '<li><a class="display_link" href="#">'+key+'</a></li>' and the use this function to append further data from json file to the 
<ul id="links"> </ul> like 'data' and 'link' no idea how to get them :/